# Where do i find the shipping methods details in the database ? woocommerce

Tags: database, wordpress, woocommerce

i am looking for the data that concerns the shipping methods details in the database like shown in the picture.

thank you for your help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTklt.png)

I have already looked in the tables
woocommerce_shipping_zone_methods
woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations
woocommerce_shipping_zones
and I did not find the data corresponding to the titles that appear on the photo

Answer (score 0):

i finaly found the data, so in order to insert a liste of shipping method title from a website to another, you need to go on wp_option and look for rows where **option_name** like **woocommerce_flat_rate_%** and insert rows into the new database.